# Multiple permuations based on 2 Enums

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I need to create test cases based on the results of 2 enums.
For example:

```
public enum Test_ID
{
    // for ram test
    test1 = 1,
    test2 ,
    test3 ,
    // for video test
    test4 ,
    test5 ,
    // many more...
}

public enum Test_Result
{
    NOT_FAIL = 0,
    FAIL 
}

public struct ResultStruct
{
    public Test_ID id;
    public Test_Result res;
}
```

And some other class result's were dependent on these 2 enums.

```
public class foo
{
    public ResultStruct[] ResStructArr =  new ResultStruct[MAX_NUM_OF_TESTS];

    public void updateTestsResults()
    {
        getResult();
        for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_NUM_OF_TESTS; i++)
        {
            if(ResStructArr[i].id == 1 && ResStructArr[i].res == FAIL ||
               ResStructArr[i].id == 2 && ResStructArr[i].res == FAIL ||
               ResStructArr[i].id == 3 && ResStructArr[i].res == FAIL )
               {
                   ramtest.result = FAIL;
               }
               else
               {
                   ramtest.result = NOT_FAIL;
               }

               // Update other tests results here
        }
    }

    public void getResult()
    {
         // get Test_ID and Test_Result and put it in struct array
    }

    // Perform tests..(Ram Test, Video tests, etc)
}
```

However for my test cases, I have to test all combinations of the 2 enums. 
Like:

For Ram:
test case 1:

> _testId = 1, _testRes = NOT_FAIL
>   _testId = 2, _testRes = NOT_FAIL
>   _testId = 3, _testRes = NOT_FAIL

test case 2:

> _testId = 1, _testRes = NOT_FAIL
>   _testId = 2, _testRes = FAIL
>   _testId = 3, _testRes = NOT_FAIL

test case 3:

> _testId = 1, _testRes = NOT_FAIL
>   _testId = 2, _testRes = FAIL
>   _testId = 3, _testRes = FAIL

test case 4:

> _testId = 1, _testRes = FAIL
>   _testId = 2, _testRes = NOT_FAIL
>   _testId = 3, _testRes = FAIL
>   and so on...

For Video:
test case 1:

> _testId = 4, _testRes = FAIL
>   _testId = 5, _testRes = FAIL

test case 2:

> _testId = 4, _testRes = PASS
>   _testId = 5, _testRes = FAIL

test case 3:

> _testId = 4, _testRes = FAIL
>   _testId = 5, _testRes = PASS
>   and so on...

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541199/instantiating-all-possible-combinations-of-enums) that I can get all the permutations of the 2 enums. But not what I wanted.

Is there any way to do this or do I have to manually write the test cases one by one?

**EDIT:**

I have edited my question so that it would be much clearer what I want to do.

I am trying to create the test cases as what I have described as above. With the help of ***William Custode***, I am able to get all the permutations of the enums. But I'm stuck at creating the test cases.

Comment: What else do you want besides all permutations?

Comment: For me, these are not test cases, but result combinations.

Comment: Am I right when I assume that you don't want ALL permutations but only certain ones? Like you don't want any combination of test results of different 'groups' (testID=1 testRES=OK and testID=4 testRES=Fail  would be an invalid combination then)? This is possible quite easily, I think. Just let me know if that's what you need.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Combination of test results from different groups would be invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know now what you need, here's my answer for you:

```
public enum Test_ID
{
  Type_MASK = 100,

  RAM    = 100,
  RAM_01 = 101,
  RAM_02 = 102,
  RAM_03 = 103,
  VIDEO    = 200,
  VIDEO_01 = 201,
  VIDEO_02 = 202,
}

public enum Test_Result
{
  nothing = 0,
  OK   = 1,
  FAIL = 99,
}
```

First, you should not use 0 as one of the result values, as 0 is the default value for int variables. You might forget to assign a value and get an invalid test result. Therefore don't use 0. Has helped me a lot to prevent mistakes.

Secondly, by using qualified names you may differentiate between test cases using the name of the enum (see static function of the `Enum` class, i.e. `Enum.GetNames()`). The easier way is using the values of the enum and separate the values into groups using division and modulo:

```
(This is C++/CLI, copied from my own code and variables renamed. You can easily convert it to C#)

public ref class CTestCase abstract
{
public:
  static Test_ID Type (Test_ID i_enTest)
  {
    return i_enTest- static_cast<Test>(Number(i_enTest));
  }

  static Test_ID Type (int i_iTest)
  {
    return static_cast<Test_ID>(i_iTest- Number(i_iTest));
  }

  static int Number (Test_ID i_enTest)
  {
    int iNumber = static_cast<int>(i_enTest) % static_cast<int>(Test_ID::Type_MASK);
    return iNumber;
  }

  static int Number (int i_iTest)
  {
    int iNumber = i_iTest% static_cast<int>(Test_ID::Type_MASK);
    return iNumber;
  }
};
```

This is not the final solution, but I think you will get the rest. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A simple nested loop statement will produce every variation of the two sets of values:

```
var tests = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Test_ID)).Cast<Test_ID>();

var results = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Test_Result)).Cast<Test_Result>();

var pairs = new List<Pair>();

foreach(var test in tests)
{
    foreach(var result in results)
    {
        pairs.Add(new Pair
            {
                Test = test,
                Result = result
            });
    }
}
```

What you want to do with that information isn't clear from your question, so the rest of this is my inference and suggestion.

It looks like your `updateRamTest` method just checks if any test failed, then the `ramTest.result` is set to `false`. So why not just omit the check on `_testId` and just say `ramTest.result = _testRes`?

Comment: Hi William, 
thanks for the prompt reply. I have tried to edit my question so that it will be much clearer. 
Thanks for solving one of my problems, that is to get all the permutations of the 2 enums. I used 'Tuple' instead of 'Pair' as I cannot find the 'Pair' class in c#4.0.

But what I am trying to do is to create the different types of test cases as shown in my question. But I'm stuck.